# Checking querystring for a not null value using JS

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check a querystring for a not null value using javascript? Can you show me an example on how to do this?

Like the IF clause of this snippet:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["someParameter"]))
        {
            DataListWithLinksID.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function parseQString() {
  var qs = new Array();
  var loc = location.search;
  if (loc) {
    loc = loc.substring(1); // lose the leading ?
    var parms = loc.split('&');
    for (var i=0;i<parms.length;i++) {
      nameValue = parms[i].split('=');
      qs[nameValue[0]]=(nameValue.length == 2)? unescape(nameValue[1]):null; // use null or ""
    }
  }
  return qs;
}
function getQSParm(parm) {
  return (qs[parm])?qs[parm]:null
}
var qs = parseQString();
// try getQstringValue.html?amount=23&emptyparm=&parmwithoutequals
alert(getQSParm("amount"));
alert(getQSParm("emptyparm"));
alert(getQSParm("parmwithoutequals"));

// your example:

window.onload=function() {
  if (getQSParm("someParameter")) {
      document.getElementById('DataListWithLinksID').style.display='none':
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```